# A wierd Mongoose error where some fields are getting updated and others aren't

Tags: node.js, arrays, mongodb, mongoose, mongoose-schema

Suppose I have two collections which are as follows :

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
},
password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
},
avatar: {
    type: String
},
date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
},
bunches: [{
    bunch: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'bunch'
    },
    bunchName: {
        name: String,
    },
    bunchId: {
        type: String
    }
}]
 });


const bunchSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
bunchId: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
},
secret: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
name: {
    type: String
},
tag: {
    type: String
},
description: {
    type: String,
},
wallpaper: {
    type: String
},
date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
},
users: [{
    user: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'user'
    },
    name: {
        type: String,
    },
    avatar: {
        type: String,
    }
}],
 });
```

**Objective** : Whenever A user wants to create a new bunch, After the creation of the new bunch, the

1. bunchId ,
2. _id of the bunch ,
3. name of the bunch

These three fields should be pushed into the bunches object of the User modal

Following is what I have coded

```
router.post("/create", [middlwares] , async (req, res) => {

const errors = validationResult(req);
if (!errors.isEmpty()) {
    // Then there are some errors
    return res.status(400).json({ errors: errors.array() })
}

const { name, secret } = req.body;
try {

    let user = await User.findOne({ _id: req.user.id });
  

    if (!user) {
        return res.status(400).json({ msg: 'please login' });
    }
    const bunchId = uuidv4();

    const bunch = new Bunch({
        name,
        bunchId,
        secret,
        users: [
            {
                user: req.user.id,
                name: user.name,
                avatar: user.avatar
            }
        ],
    });

    // hash the secret & save the bunch
    const salt = await bcrypt.genSalt(10);
    bunch.secret = await bcrypt.hash(secret, salt);
    await bunch.save();

    let bunchArr = [];
    bunchArr = user.bunches;

    console.log("before", bunchArr);

    let newBunchArr = [...bunchArr, { bunchName: name, bunch: bunch.id, bunchId }];

    console.log("after", newBunchArr);


    

    await User.findOneAndUpdate({ _id: req.user.id }, { $set: { bunches: newBunchArr } });
    // generate a payload
    const payload = {
        user: {
            id: user.id,
        },
        bunch: {
            id: bunch.id
        }
    };

    jwt.sign(
        payload,
        config.get('jwtSecret'),
        { expiresIn: 360000 },
        (err, token) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            res.json({ token });
        }
    );

} catch (error) {
    console.error(error.message);
    res.status(500).send('server error');
}
 });
```

I expect the await User.findOneAndUpdate.... line should push all the three above mentioned 3 fields into the mongo DB databse
Not just like this but I tried acheiving this by many other methods which include

`users.bunches.unshift({.. the object..});  await user.save();`

and some others but none of them worked

THE ISSUE :
In all the ways I tried, only the bunch , and bunchId fields are beng updated in the mongo database but the **name field is not being pushed**

[image: have a look]

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You have an error in your `User` Schema:

```
const userSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
name: {
    type: String,
    required: true
},
email: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
    unique: true,
},
password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
},
avatar: {
    type: String
},
date: {
    type: Date,
    default: Date.now
},
bunches: [{
    bunch: {
        type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
        ref: 'bunch'
    },
    bunchName: {
        name: String, ---> this should be type: String 
    },
    bunchId: {
        type: String
    }
}]
 });
```